# Embedded if statement in a PHP generated table

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a table built by PHP. Sometimes a value in $row[6], $row[7], and/or $row[8] might be "none" (not NULL). When that happens, I would like to echo a blank space. I realize this will likely take an IF statement, but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)){
echo "<tr>";        
echo "<td>  {$row[1]} </td>";
echo "<td>  {$row[2]} </td>";
echo "<td>  {$row[3]} </td>";
echo "<td>  {$row[4]} </td>";
echo "<td>  {$row[5]} </td>";
echo "<td>  {$row[6]} </td>";
echo "<td>  <a href='{$row[7]}'>BluuGnome</a>                       
        <a href='{$row[8]}'>CanyoneeringUSA</a>
        <a href='{$row[9]}'>Climb UT</a> </td>";
```

Comment: Right now, I don't see where you close your `<tr>`, and it looks like all of the other `$row[i]` are inside cells, not rows... What did you want the final thing to look like?

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 0):

Read http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.if.php about the if statement. You can nest this inside the while block like

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)){
  ...
  if($row[1] == "none") {
    echo "";
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: You may also want to use &nbsp; instead of "" for the space in HTML. Ie. echo "&nbsp;";

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the ternary operator:

```
   $row[6] == 'None' ? echo "<td>  {$row[6]} </td>" : echo "<td> </td>";
```

Comment: First, you should put the `echo` before the ternary operation (i.e.  `echo ($x ? $a : $b);`. It is cleaner. Second, using a simple `if` statement here would probably be nicer in the long run. When it comes to maintaining code the more straight forward it is the better.

Answer (score 0):

Combination of a couple of the above answers:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
    echo '<tr>';        
    for(i=0; i<9; i++) {
        ($row[i] == 'none') ? echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>' : echo '<td>' . $row[i] . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```